# How to find the first Non-NAN data before Nan in one column in Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, nan

For example,
I have some data like this:

```
column = pd.Series([1,2,3,np.nan,4,np.nan,7])
print column
```

Executing the command, the result looks like:

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    NaN
4    4.0
5    NaN
6    7.0
```

Now I want to know what is the first value before each NaN value, such as 3.0 which is before the first NaN. And 4.0 is the result before the second NaN value. Is there any built-in function in pandas which can complete this or shall I write a for loop to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same idea as @jezrael... `numpy`fied.

```
column[np.append(np.isnan(column.values)[1:], False)]

2    3.0
4    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Complete with `pd.Series` reconstruction

```
m = np.append(np.isnan(column.values)[1:], False)
pd.Series(column.values[m], column.index[m])

2    3.0
4    4.0
dtype: float64
```

---

Not nearly as quick but intuitive.  Group by the the `cumsum` of `isnull` and take the last value.  Of this result, get rid of last row.

```
column.groupby(column.isnull().cumsum()).last().iloc[:-1]

0    3.0
1    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution working with non consecutive `NaN`s.
You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask created by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html), [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
print (column[column.isnull().shift(-1).fillna(False)])
2    3.0
4    4.0
dtype: float64
```

---

```
print (column.isnull())
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool

print (column.isnull().shift(-1))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6      NaN
dtype: object

print (column.isnull().shift(-1).fillna(False))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

With consecutive `NaN`s need multiple by inverted `c` by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
column = pd.Series([np.nan,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,7,np.nan, np.nan, 5,np.nan])

c = column.isnull()
mask = c.shift(-1).fillna(False).mul(~c)
print (mask)
0     False
1     False
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7     False
8     False
9      True
10    False
dtype: bool

print (column[mask])
2    3.0
6    7.0
9    5.0
dtype: float64
```